What's the best policy for rapid revisions to multiple questions?
I've recently seen the front page loaded with a lot of (good) edits to previously asked questions; often the edits are not from the OP but rather from others with the authority to edit.
I believe that touching a posting even lightly for a minor revision bumps the question to the front, while pushing other newer questions down off the queue. Also (I think) we seem to get fewer questions during the weekend than during the weekday.
For the above reasons, when I've done similar editing of my posts and others I've tried to do maybe three or four at most, and mostly on the weekend, so as to not bump other newer and fresher good questions and answers off the front.
Should we encourage such a policy or does it matter in the long run, and it's OK to let people edit as they see fit?

I was wondering whether this would come up at some point. Similar to what you wrote, when I edit a batch of old posts I pay attention to 1. not doing it more than once a week 2. limiting myself to $\leq$10 at a time (as you said, to not bury the front page)  3. doing it when not much else is expected to happen on the site. So I do agree with your methods -- and I hope that such edits do not come across as spamming the site, resp. the feed. Either way (+1), some moderator input on this to have a rough guideline might be good.

Thanks! I think the 10 edits is a little high is all!

Not making "too many" consecutive edits avoids cluttering the active page, but also means not making edits that might be needed/useful. Such "mass edits" are most often (but not always) due to retagging, eg removing obsolete tags from questions, adding newly created tags to relevant questions, and such.
So what should take priority, making editing to questions to improve the overall organisation on the site, or leaving things as they are to avoid bumping too many questions? Or if we go for a middle ground, where exactly is the threshold we should strive for?
I doubt there's any objective answer to these questions. It's also going to come down to how different people use the site, and how much different people prefer to optimise for long-term vs short-term site usefulness.
Personally, I've always cared more about overall organisation than how cluttered the main page is. In fact, I essentially do not use at all the "active questions" tab, which is the only place where this problem arises.
If you do use it (which is totally fine, of course), I understand seeing too many old bumped questions might be annoying. But also, if your goal is looking for new questions... why not simply use the "newest questions" tab?
In conclusion, I'm not sure what kind of policy one could or should come up with, other than "don't overdo it!". Setting fixed thresholds doesn't sound ideal: some edits might be more important than others, so it feels like such thresholds should depend on the importance of the edits. But then coming up with a table of thresholds to account for this seems way too much of an overkill.
Also, what if different people are concurrently working on similar types of edits? If the threshold is, say, "five edits per person per day", and three people are doing them at the same time, is that fine or not? It'd still be cluttering the page as if a single person was doing 15 edits at the same time.

Thanks for the comment and feedback! New users don’t know to check the “active questions” tag I suppose. If a new user posts a good question that gets bumped from main, then her question might not get the visibility she wants (of course there are a lot of vehicles to address this including bounties). But I agree everything in moderation!

I know this has probably been asked too many times to count but it would be great for a “this is a minor edit, don’t bump” button? That would address both sides to the ‘’yes, but” balance.

@MarkSpinelli I don't disagree (though it's not clear how you'd prevent people from abusing it to make "stealth edits"), but regardless, it's not really something we can do anything about ourselves. It was suggested on meta before, eg https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567/276202, but it doesn't seem to be a planned feature

Stealth edits could be mitigated based on reputation? E.g only allow for the button for those with rep greater than even the rep to edit without review… or something. Thanks for the link! I’ll check it out.

@MarkSpinelli there might be a way to make it work yes, but you'd need to convince employees to work on the feature. Currently not even mods can edit posts without bumping them (except for tag merging)

fair thanks! --

The suggestions most helpful on Meta are: fix most important questions and worst titles, but even salutation removal edits have their supporters and opponents. It's also a question of how visible the bumps are on the front page; low activity sites that are all bumps isn't good.
You can use your Saves list (create a new list and label it) to create a list of edits to be spread out over a long period of time; really great edits that are most necessary and haven't missed anything should draw the least ire.

I agree. I try to limit my minor editing of ancient posts, so that I don't bury new questions so far away from the top.
A long time ago I made a public "pending edits" page here, and made those edits on low-traffic days, then crossed those edits off of the "pending edits" list.
If you see one user making minor edits on more than 5 ancient posts in one day (for example), perhaps you can refer them to this Meta thread that you have just started, to point out that it's discouraged. When a user edits a post, they become pingable (although for some reason, their username won't be auto-filled, so you'll have to type it in full yourself, but the user will be notified, unlike when you try to ping someone who has not authored, edited, or commented on the post).

Thanks for your perspective! I don't think I'm the only one who does this but I will often fixate on some of my contributions that I'm proud of, and will still cringe at what I see are minor (or often major) blemishes. I'll add a comment in the posting to the effect of "Note to self: XYZ is incorrect - fix this later when not so busy."

Two other dumb questions: (1) How do you know or how can you predict when traffic is not so bad, and am I right that the weekends are generally slower, and (2) when you say to ping a user, I guess you mean to add a comment in their posting to say "Hi At-So-and-So, I see you're making a lot of good edits in rapid succession; can you check out this meta post for some perspectives about this?"

I hadn't considered adding something like "Note to self: fix XYZ later when not so busy". I've been keeping those notes in a personal "to-do list" file that I save and update on GitHub. I sometimes also have <!-- comments --> in the HTML code of my answers on SE. You're right that weekends are slower: you can click on the review queue, then on "Tools", then on "Site analytics" (for stats on the main site, make sure you do this on the main site rather than the meta site). This will show you that activity noticeably decreases on weekends. Also you're correct about what I mean by "ping a user"!

I just took a look here and clicked on all the significant peaks in post activity, and found that all of them were on weekdays or Sundays (a Sunday in the UTC time zone is a Monday in some parts of the world). Not one of those peaks was on a Saturday.
